# Cannot add values to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, side-menu

I have two view controllers, one of them part being a side menu.
I try to init its cells with data from an array but I keep having errors when trying to assign a value to a cell label text.
Here is the code I have:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
}


class SideMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let vc = ViewController()
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return vc.array.count

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "checkbox")
        cell.cellLabel.text = "test" //HERE IS THE ERROR
        cell.cellImage.image = myImage
        return cell
    }

}
```

And here is the error.

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In the debugger, I can see that my cell contains the label and image from the `Sotryboard` but I cannot assign `myImage` and any text to the cell.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash? Are the outlets connected in the cell?

Comment: Thanks @maddy, I had not connected the outlets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu?s=1|489.4274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
```

is causing the crash. Did you remember to set the class of your cell prototype in `Storyboard` to `TableViewCell`?

Comment: Also don't forget to set the identifier to "cell"

Comment: Yes I did. The problem's origin is forgetting to connect the outlets.

Answer (score 1):

Check :
1. Custom cell has reusableCellIdentifier set in xib.

[image]

2. If you are using xib for custom cell, custom cell should be registered with `UITableView` :

> tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:
>   "yourIdentifier")